# Is there some numpy trick i can use to replace this for loop?

Tags: python, numpy

Assume grid_sheet is an array (1000, 1000, 3)

and

array2 is numpy array shaped (13k-ish, 3).

We're basically treating this array2 like a list. A list of rgb value combinations. Each combination is unique.

And grid_sheet should be treated like a screenshot as if you've used snipping tool to create the image.

```
blank_sheet = np.zeros((grid_sheet.shape[0], grid_sheet.shape[1]))
for data in array2:
    blank_sheet = np.where(((grid_sheet[:,:,2] == data[2]) & (grid_sheet[:,:,1] == data[1]) & (grid_sheet[:,:,0] == data[0])), blank_sheet+1, blank_sheet)
```

The output would be like a boolean array the same size as the grid_sheet.
I don't want to use a for loop on array2 because it's just too slow.

I've tried splitting the channels to compare to their corresponding columns but when dstacking and summing it all back together just shows it marks nearly then entire grid with 1s. Results are the same if i merge the values together flatten then compare and then reshape to an image representable way. There are a number of other idea's i've tried, plenty of stackoverflow solutions i've tried to merge with others. I hardly see any point in nditer. someone tried suggesting itertools but i don't think the 2 mesh well together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for this purpose. But first we have to add [additional axes](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html?numpy.newaxis#numpy.newaxis) and slightly reorganize data.

To apply comparison along the third axis we have to transpose the array with colors, so that its colors are numbered by second index. And put two additional dimensions at the beginning to fit with the image plane:

```
colors = array2.T[None,None,:,:]
```

Now `colors` has 4 dimensions and its shape is `(1, 1, 3, len(array2))`. Next step is to add forth dimension to the image which will correspond the index of each color of the array2:

```
image = grid_sheet[:,:,:,None]
```

Now `image` has also 4 dimensions and its shape is `(1000, 1000, 3, 1)`. If we compare `image` and `colors`, the comparison will be done along the third axis, i.e. by colors only. To find out if all parts of a color match the color in the image point we apply `all(2)`, where 2 addresses the third axis. Then we apply `any` along the last dimension in order to find if any of the given colors matches the color of the image point:

```
result = (image == colors).all(2).any(2)
```

Note, that after the `all` method the number of dimentions has been reduced by 1, so the index of the last dimension will be 2. That's why we put 2 as the parameter of `any`.

**Test case**

```
from numpy import arange, array, newaxis

image = arange(3*3*2).reshape(3,3,2)
colors = array([[0,1], [2,3], [4,5], [8,9]])

expected = array([
    [ True,  True,  True],
    [False,  True, False],
    [False, False, False]
])

image = image[:, :, :, newaxis]
colors = colors.T[newaxis, newaxis, :, :]

assert colors.shape == (1,1,2,4)
assert image.shape == (3,3,2,1)

result = (image == colors).all(2).any(2)

assert (result == expected).all()
```

**An example with Dask to process big pictures**

```
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da
from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client(n_workers=4)
display(client)

# X, Y : a size of an image
# N : a number of colors to check
X, Y, N = 1080, 1920, 13921

# dX, dY, dN : dimensions of chunks for dask.array
# values vary by computer
dX, dY, dN = 360, 640, 500

image = np.arange(X*Y*3).reshape(X, Y, 3)
colors = np.arange(N*3).reshape(N, 3)

image = image[:, :, :, None]
colors = colors.T[None, None, :, :]

# a shape of chunks should resemble the logic of broadcasting
im = da.from_array(image, chunks=(dX, dY, 3, 1))
co = da.from_array(colors, chunks=(1, 1, 3, dN))

im, co = da.broadcast_arrays(im, co)

re = (im == co).all(2).any(2)

result = re.compute()

assert result.shape == (X, Y)
assert result.sum() == N
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i upvoted this for the effort. I really appreciate the help. I'm currently trying this out but for some reason it keeps pulling up this error.
DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
result = (image == colors).all(2).any(2)
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'

just to clarify, your example does work, but when i stitch in my image and list to image and colors, it just doesnt seem to act accordingly.

Comment: Check the shape of the `image` and `colors`. Follow the example. What is `colors.shape` and `image.shape` in your case?

Comment: my image is (1080, 1920, 3)
and colors is (13921, 3)
it might not matter too much but their datatypes are uint8. i change the shapes of your samples to match mine and they work just fine interchangeably. its just when i apply both of my entries.

Comment: @DuckWizard Before comparison we have to be sure that it's possible to do. So the shape of `image` shuld be `(1080, 1920, 3, 1)` and the shape of `colors` should be `(1, 1, 3, 13921)`. The data inside stay the same, we just have to reorganise their layout.

Comment: Yes. They got reshaped to those exact numbers.

Comment: Could any previews procedures affect the colors data maybe? i broadcasted a boolean to the colors to get it to that (axishere, 3) shape. and before that i applied a 90 degree rotation to the image. there really isnt anything special about the image. its just a simple fullscreen screenshot.

Comment: @DuckWizard I suppose it's about memory. The picture of elementwise comparison is gonna be huge, that's may cause to return False instead of ndarray.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247931/discussion-between-duck-wizard-and-vitalizzare).